# Server Side Includes are not being shown

Tags: ssi

I've gone through every fix online I'm pretty sure but I just can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to have <#include virtual="footer.ssi" but not matter what it doesn't work. 
footer.ssi and the page are in the same place 
I really have no clue how to fix this issue but I can't get ANY server sides to show up on any of my pages so I know it's on my end. If anyone has any thoughts they're greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you are using and maybe the browser error messages that are appearing in the console as well.

Comment: If you want help, you need to respond to comments and answers.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was useful to you (click the check mark). Please comment if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code should be this: `<!--#include virtual="footer.ssi" -->`, this is what I use on my website, and it works perfectly!

See this reference: [Html Goodies](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm), and scroll down to **The File Argument** section.